# Using both setExtremes and afterSetExtremes in HighStocks

Tags: jquery, events, highcharts, navigator

with highcharts, i'm trying to use both setExtremes and afterSetExtremes in a way, that the text updates what range is selected instantly, but after mouseup, the chart also loads data and use it.

In the following fiddle, i'm trying to update the text in #report as soon as the range slider updates.

http://jsfiddle.net/4eh6uL6b/1/

The relevant part be:

```
xAxis : {
  events : {
   afterSetExtremes : afterSetExtremes,
   setExtremes : setExtremes
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what is wrong, because in your example it seems to working fine.

Comment: as it says in the question .. i'm trying to update #report WHILE i'm dragging the handles on the navigator ..  not after it settles ..  like it does here:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/xaxis/events-setextremes/

Comment: Try to set [liveRedraw](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#scrollbar.liveRedraw) flag as true.

Comment: @SebastianBochan i tried that ..  but then it sends rapid the ajax calls on every change ..  i want those to go with afterSetExtremes (as in after i LEAVE the handle of navigator)

Comment: An example in your comment loads all the data in usdeur.js by single step. Your original example loads data async in the afterSetExtremes event hundler. So what way do you prefer?

Comment: The problem is that in afterSetExtremes you call setData, which call setExtremes and then afterSetExtremes. As a result you have a infinity loop, also when liveRedraw is set as false. Try to set any variable as flag which skip this situation.

Comment: What i need is actually both. I need to set series (via data from ajax) when the user has finished setting the range, but i want to show the user WHAT range he's selecting before he sets it (during the dragging of the handle).

I can't seem to be able to do both.